# Question about Rigify's "Special" bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

everyone. I have a question about Rigify, sorry for terrible English.
The question is about bones in "Special" bone group, they have yellow wireframe.

For example, Rigify human rig has "chest" bone.
When I rotate this bone, "spine_fk.002" bone is rotated. No problem, I know why it is.
[image]

When I rotate "spine_fk.002" bone, "chest" bone is rotated. However, I can't find "chest" bone's dependency on "spine_fk.002". I think it has no constraint and is located at higher in hierarchy than "spine_fk.002" bone. Do anyone know why "chest" is rotated like this?
[image]
I want to know it and make this from scratch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chest bone itself doesn't move.

You can see that if you remove custom shape:

[image]

But what really changes is the bone shape. Override transform is used to display bone in different place, while in reality it not depends on spine_fk.002 to avoid loop in parents errors:

[image]